# Sequences of SDEs

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, skorohod-space

I've been looking for a while an cannot seem to find the answer to this question:

*If $Y_n$ is a sequenence of semi-martingales solving the sequence of stochastic differential equations:
$$
dY_n(t) = \mu_n(t,Y_n(t))dt + \Sigma_n(t,Y_n(t))dW(t)
$$
where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are simple adapted processes to the filtration of the $d$-dimensional Brownian motion $W_t$ then is $\mu_n,\Sigma_n$ converge to adapted processes $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ does $\lim_{n \mapsto \infty} Y_n(t)$ solve the Stochastic Differential Equation:
$$
dY(t) = \mu(t,Y(t))dt + \Sigma(t,Y(t))dW(t)?
$$*

Comment: You must have a typo and meant to write $$dY_n(t) = \mu_n(t, Y_n(t))\,dt + \Sigma_n(t, Y_n(t))\, dW(t)$$ otherwise, you are at risk of $Y_n = Y_m$ for every $n, m$, which renders the problem trivial.

Comment: @Noober : I think the book by Ethier and Kurtz "Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence" have such theroems for Markovian processes, as your sequence seems regular enough to be diffusions (whcih are markovian) it might do the trick. Best regard

Comment: Can you refer me to a specific page or chapter, I looked but didn't find the results I needed...